# Internal server error in jquery /json webmethod

Tags: jquery

> Here am calling a web method on click event. but am getting the error as inernal server error. here am calling this click event from dynamically created button . this is asp.net with c# code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#contaner_wrapper').css("height", "100%");
       $(document).on('click', '.fc-button-prev a span', function () {                
        //alert($("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString());
           var abc = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString();
           var ab = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').end.toString();
           //PageMethods.EventDetails('E72', onSucess, onError);
           $.ajax({
               url: 'ViewEvents.aspx/Displaymonthevents',
               type: 'POST',
               data: 'hi',
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (data) {
                   alert(data.d);
               },
               error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   alert(errorThrown);
               }
       });
       $(document).on('click', '.fc-button-next a span', function () {
           // Displaymonthevents();                 
           alert($("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString());
           var abc = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString();
           var ab = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').end.toString();
           jQuery.ajax({
               url: "ViewEvents.aspx/EventDetails",
               type: "POST",
               data: "hi",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {
                   alert(data.d);
               }
           });
       });

       $(".fc-button-prev a span").trigger('click');
       $(".fc-button-next a span").trigger('click');
   });

</script>` [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public List<Events> Displaymonthevents(string eventdata1)
    {            List<Events> events;         return events;
    }
```

Comment: Do the url's ViewEvents.aspx/EventDetails & ViewEvents.aspx/Displaymonthevents work when you browse to them manually?

Comment: How to browse manually, am put breakpoint in c#. but it is not firing.

Comment: I think it's more your executable code in ViewEvents.aspx then it is your jQuery. Which seems fine to me.